# Stretch table without breaking lines

Tags: tabu

I'd like to stretch below tabular to a width of 15 cm width which is wider than the original table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
& Jan & Feb & Mar & Apr & May & Jun & Jul & Aug & Sep & Oct & Nov & Dec\\
\hline
2016 & 2.5 & 1.3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
\hline
2015 & & 0.6 & 5.2 & 8.5 & 0.3 & 1.4 & 0.5 & 3.9 & 7.1 & 2.4 & 2.3 & -999.9\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I use the tabu environment as shown below. While this produces a table with desired width, long cells now contain a line break (see cell for Dec 2015).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} to 15cm {|X[l]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|}
\hline
& Jan & Feb & Mar & Apr & May & Jun & Jul & Aug & Sep & Oct & Nov & Dec\\
\hline
2016 & 2.5 & 1.3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
\hline
2015 & & 0.6 & 5.2 & 8.5 & 0.3 & 1.4 & 0.5 & 3.9 & 7.1 & 2.4 & 2.3 & -999.9\\
\hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I stretch the table to fill the available width without breaking cell content in two lines?

Answer (score 2):

A comment up front: If a font size of 10pt (or larger) is in use, then the contents of the table won't fit if it's only 15 cm wide. I suggest you increase its width, say to `\textwidth`.

I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment instead of the basic `tabular` environment, and use a modified (viz., ragged-left) version of the `X` column type for columns 2 thru 13.

Separately, you may also want to consider giving the table a more "open" look, by omitting all vertical lines and having fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines. The second table in the following screenshot illustrates such an open look, achieved with the help of the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

With lots of horizontal and vertical lines:

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{12}{R|}}
\hline
& Jan & Feb & Mar & Apr & May & Jun & Jul & Aug & Sep & Oct & Nov & Dec\\
\hline
2016 & 2.5 & 1.3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
\hline
2015 & & 0.6 & 5.2 & 8.5 & 0.3 & 1.4 & 0.5 & 3.9 & 7.1 & 2.4 & 2.3 & $-999.9$\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip\bigskip
With \emph{no} vertical lines and fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines:

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{12}{R}}
\toprule
& Jan & Feb & Mar & Apr & May & Jun & Jul & Aug & Sep & Oct & Nov & Dec\\
\midrule
2016 & 2.5 & 1.3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
2015 & & 0.6 & 5.2 & 8.5 & 0.3 & 1.4 & 0.5 & 3.9 & 7.1 & 2.4 & 2.3 & $-999.9$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should mentioned in answer, that you use full text width of page (and not only 15cm) and by this avoid to the OP problem ... Use of `tabularx`   is better than use of (not maintained) `tabu`.

Comment: @zarko - If the table is supposed to be 15cm wide and a 10pt (or larger) font size is in use, the final "-999.9" won't fit in the allocated cell. I'll make this more explicit in my write-up.

Comment: @Mico The same table fits into a `tabular` of less than 15cm width using the same font size. Why will the table not fit into a `tabu` or `tabularx` which is wider than the original table?

Comment: @lukas - The table "fits" in a `tabular` environment because the columns aren't equally wide. If you want the twelve data columns to have equal widths -- a reasonable thing, in my view... -- *and* stick with the original width of 15 cm, you'd have to reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace by about 50% to get the table to "fit", virtually guaranteeing a collision of the material in the final two columns.